# Replacing a while loop with a for statement with python list

Tags: python

I have to create a list of cars, a function to display the cars but replace the fourth car with a phrase, and call the function, for an assignment. One of the parts of the grading scheme is to use a for statement to iterate, not a while loop. It also says that it can be done in under 10 lines of code.

I have created a while loop that does prints the proper list, but I cannot manage to change it to a for statement successfully.

```
def my_Assign3_challenge(cars):
  i=0
  while i<len(cars):
    print(cars[i])
    i=i+1
    if i==3:
      print("I would never buy that!")
      i=i+1
cars=["toyota","mitsubishi","dodge","ford","mini"]
my_Assign3_challenge(cars)
```

This for statement just prints the list, without the change:

```
def my_Assign3_challenge(cars):
  for x in cars:
    if x!= 3:
      print(x)
    else:
      print("I would never buy that!")
cars=["toyota","mitsubishi","dodge","ford","mini"]
my_Assign3_challenge(cars)
```

I also managed a couple times to have just the first list item repeat indefinitely, I can't find the code that did that now, though.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could take a look at this and tell me where I went wrong. I'm sure it's just a simple mistake, as I am very new to coding, but I would love your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop iterates through the list indices ...

```
while i<len(cars):
  print(cars[i])
```

... but you changed your referencing with the `for` loop: you now reference the elements themselves, the brand names:

```
for x in cars:
```

but you still treat `x` as if it were an integer index.
Since `x` is now a sequence of brand names, it will *never* equal `3`.  You need to make up your mind which way you're going to refer to the list elements, and make your second set of code use that way consistently.

Comment: Thank you! That got me on the right track and I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

The for loop in the function:

```py
def my_Assign3_challenge(cars):
  for x in cars:
    if x!= 3:
      print(x)
    else:
      print("I would never buy that!")
cars=["toyota","mitsubishi","dodge","ford","mini"]
my_Assign3_challenge(cars)
```

Outputs

```
toyota
mitsubishi
dodge
ford
mini
```

You need to get the index using `.index()`

The code would be:

```py
def my_Assign3_challenge(cars):
  for x in cars:
    if cars.index(x) != 3:
      print(x)
    else:
      print("I would never buy that!")
cars=["toyota","mitsubishi","dodge","ford","mini"]
my_Assign3_challenge(cars)
```

Comment: The `.index(...)` call would return the index of the first matching value so the above solution fails when, e.g., `cars=["toyota","ford","dodge","ford","mini"]`. Have a look at the `enumerate(...)` function which yields (index, value).

Answer (score 0):

I can do it in 3 lines:

```
challenge = lambda x : [v if i !=3 else "I would never buy that!" for i, v in enumerate(x)]
cars=["toyota","mitsubishi","dodge","ford","mini"]
challenge(cars)
```

output:

```
Out[54]: ['toyota', 'mitsubishi', 'dodge', 'I would never buy that!', 'mini']
```

Comment: What's the point of the lambda? Just replace `x` with `cars` in the lost-comp...

Comment: The function can be called on an arbitrary input list with lambda

Comment: Then why not just define a function? Lambdas are *nameless* functions. Assigning them to a variable mostly goes against their purpose...

Comment: Less lines, haha.

Comment: Less lines doesn't mean better code. In most cases even the opposite

Comment: True, but if the challenge is to restrict the number of lines you might as well provide just one.